# Swiper slider do not work after infinite scroll load more information

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart, swipe, infinite-scroll

I'm using [Swiper slider](https://swiperjs.com/) for some images on homepage with [infinite scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/) to load more information on scrolling on Opencart platform.

The problem is coming when i scrolling down and more content is loaded with infinite scroll than Swiper Slider arrows are not working for the new content

I initialize Swiper in a footer to be sure will be initialize after home is loaded even i do it with loop but still same issue

Any ideas how I can sort out this issue ?

Swiper

```
$(".swiper-container").each(function(index, element) {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination'
        },
        spaceBetween: 10,
    });
});
```

Infinite scroll

```
 $("#listproduct").addClass("infinitescroll");
 var $container = $('.infinitescroll');

 $container.infinitescroll({
     navSelector: ".pagination",
     nextSelector: ".next-pagination",
     itemSelector: ".product-layout",
     history: 'push',
     loading: {
         msgText: "Loading ....",
     }
 },
```

**UPDATE**

I manage to make it work with next changes

Swiper

```
var options = {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination'
        },
        spaceBetween: 10,
    },

swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', options);
```

Infinite

```
$("#listproduct").addClass("infinitescroll");
var $container = $('.infinitescroll');

 $container.infinitescroll({
 navSelector: ".pagination",
 nextSelector: ".next-pagination",
 itemSelector: ".product-layout",
 history: 'push',
 loading: {
     msgText: "Loading ....",
 }
},function(){
 swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', options);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, but you need to put your answer in an answer (and accept it) so this post can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like destroy is called somewhere in the infinite scroll and Swiper must be re-initialize once loading is finished this will work for v2 infinite

Swiper

```
var options = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination'
    },
    spaceBetween: 10,
},

swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', options);
```

Infinite

```
$("#listproduct").addClass("infinitescroll");
var $container = $('.infinitescroll');

 $container.infinitescroll({
 navSelector: ".pagination",
 nextSelector: ".next-pagination",
 itemSelector: ".product-layout",
 history: 'push',
 loading: {
     msgText: "Loading ....",
 }
},function(){
 swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swiper has an `update` method in [its API](https://swiperjs.com/api/#methods):

```
swiper.update();
```

You'll need to run that in your infinite scroll [load](https://infinite-scroll.com/events.html#load) event [callback](https://infinite-scroll.com/events.html#jquery-event-binding). That might look like this:

```
$container.on( 'load.infiniteScroll', function() {
    swiper.update();
});
```

Comment: not sure if i do it right but as i read in infinite scroll v2 after initialize i should call function(item){
      var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper
      mySwiper.update();
    }  
but still not working

Comment: I've updated the answer. What you've shown doesn't seem to be an event callback.

Comment: i tried with the new update but still not working even if i console.log('fine') inside the $container.on .... not showing in the console

Comment: I would need to see a full demo to help further. I'm guessing in the dark otherwise. You might try to set it up on one of the JavaScript playground sites.

Comment: im glad you spend your time trying to help me your post look right but didnt work for me (look like destory is called somewhere in infinite scroll) anyway i wil give a vote in case someone need it and i update my topic with the way is working for me . thanks